# Ubuntu 18.04 - Programs disappearing or breaking after reboot

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I installed Jack audio server in my last session on Ubuntu 18.04 using the normal procedure by `sudo apt install jackd qjackctl` and had a very painful work configuring everything to get it working with both ALSA and Pulseaudio. Finally, I also installed KXStudio Cadence to improve Jack functionalities.

After rebooting the system, all these softwares completely vanished from the system. I can't find them in the application list from MATE nor by typing qjackctl, jackd or cadence on the terminal. I get the message they're not installed. But whenever I try to install them again, it fails saying there are missing dependencies, which are not  going to be installed. (This message is very recurrent and shows how Ubuntu's Advanced Packaging Tool (apt) is unreliable.)

When running `apt list --installed`, they're not listed. But when running `sudo apt autoremove` the cadence tools are listed there as garbage to be removed, but not the Jack tools. I also installed other software in my last session, which are still there. Can someone explain what is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to reinstall the packages using `aptitude` instead of `apt`, which is apparently of higher level.

However, I could not understand why the installations disappeared, but I suppose it is related to the fact I had to swich the laptop off and on again due to keyboard freezing on a session restore. If this is the reason, it means that Ubuntu probably has a kind of pointer pointing to successful installations and whenever an installation seems to be broken or incomplete, it flags this as not installed and try pointing all related data as garbage for the `autoremove` to remove it.